# Как создать объект из значений данных?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сформировать объект значений из забранных данных. Приведу простой пример

```js
$(".btn_start").on("click", function() {
  var myArr = {};
  var currentButton = $(".myButton");

  var myKey = currentButton.data("key");
  var myValue = currentButton.data("value");

  myArr[myKey] = myArr.myValue;
  alert("myArr =" + myArr);

});
```

```css
button {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="myButton" data-key="myKey1" data-value="valueNumber1">Button</button>
<button class="myButton" data-key="myKey2" data-value="valueNumber2">Button</button>
<button class="myButton" data-key="myKey3" data-value="valueNumber3">Button</button>
<button class="myButton" data-key="myKey4" data-value="valueNumber1">Button</button>
<div class="bl_withButton">
  <button class="btn_start">Start</button>
</div>
```

Как по нажатию на кнопку .btn_start получить объект у которого ключами бы были значения кнопок data-key а значениями их data-value? Как получить это в объект myArr ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(".btn_start").on("click", function() {
  const myArr = {};
  const currentButton = $(".myButton");

  // currentButton это список объектов, поэтому нужен цикл
  currentButton.each((idx, button) => {
    myArr[button.dataset.key] = button.dataset.value;
  });

  console.log("myArr =", myArr);
});
```

```css
button {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="myButton" data-key="myKey1" data-value="valueNumber1">Button</button>
<button class="myButton" data-key="myKey2" data-value="valueNumber2">Button</button>
<button class="myButton" data-key="myKey3" data-value="valueNumber3">Button</button>
<button class="myButton" data-key="myKey4" data-value="valueNumber1">Button</button>
<div class="bl_withButton">
  <button class="btn_start">Start</button>
</div>
```

**Полезные ссылки**
[dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) 
[$.each](https://jquery-docs.ru/each/) 
[arrowFunction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)